# display inline-block. How to prevent pushing the block to the new line?

Tags: html, css

The code is on the screen. Just display:inline-block. When on the window there are no space to place a block than it is moved down to the new line. I wanna to make as on the screen in a green rectangle. So that the blocks move outsize the window(if no space) and appears scrollbar to see this blocks.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outer div just needs the css property `white-space: nowrap;`

[See the jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/xg76z8ab/2/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a horizontal scroll bar, you must do two things:  Give the container an explicit width, and the property `overflow-x: auto`.

Using `display: inline-block` will cause the content inside the element to behave like a block, but treat the whole container as inline, which is to take up as much horizontal space as possible until it encounters an edge, and then flow to the next line.

IMHO, your best best is to give the container holding the elements an explicit height (enough to contain just one of your child blocks), and then give it an explicit width of 100% of container size (you may need to use actual pixels; 100% will only work if you have relative positioning setup correctly).  Finally, overflow-x: auto, and you should get the rendering you want.